# Special characters (e. g. umlauts) not displayed correctly in *Org tags* fast tag selection buffer

Tags: org-mode

In the "*Org tags*" buffer (the buffer showing the fast tag selection keys when pressing C-c C-c C-c in a headline) some fast selection keys are shown as e. g. [\212] instead of the actual key. How can I fix this?

emacs-version: GNU Emacs 24.4.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.4 (Build 13E28)) of 2014-07-05